# '${}' doesn't work as intented in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

I have some code and when I type '${prefix}test' instead of making it !test it is ${prefix}test

```
console.log('${bot.user.tag} logged in.');
```

What this says is ${bot.user.tag} logged in. not Friend logged in.

Comment: You need to use backticks and not single quotes to denote [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) use the backtick `\``, not the apostrophe `'`.

Comment: The backtick make it work perfectly but how do I get it on my keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are just missing back-ticks. This is known as a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
console.log(`${bot.user.tag} logged in.`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks (character on the tilde `~` key) for template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
let bot = {user: {tag: 'foo'}}
console.log(`${bot.user.tag} logged in.`);
```

Comment: Note: it's not below the tilde on all keyboard layouts. For example, on my UK Qwerty layout, it's above the `tab` key.

Comment: I edited it, it's *on* the tilde key for me, *above* the tab key

Comment: Ah, yeah for me tilde is above my right shift key and the pound `#` symbol is on my tilde. I just thought I'd note it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Backtick for template literals [article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/string-interpolation-in-javascript/)

```js
let bot = { user: { tag: "Friend" }};
console.log(`${bot.user.tag} logged in.`);
```